# understanding audio player and post back of web page

Tags: ajax, postback, html5-audio, audio-streaming, asp.net-webpages

I have a web page with search text box, to search movies.

1. user search a movie and press enter. Then I list down all the songs of that movie in a list.
2. User clicks a song from the list of songs and that song start playing in audio player in my web page.

If user want to listen/Browse songs from different movie they type in the movie name in my search box and press enter. Now a post back occurs this post back stops the song that users is listening to.

I don't want my audio player to stop or pause playing on post-back. I cannot go ahead with ajax call. it has to be a complete post back.

I have seen this working (as expected above) in Gaana.com. In gaana.com entire page get postback but the player continues to play the song it is playing without a pause or stop.

Please let me know how can this be achieved.

Comment: I am still not sure this can be done without using AJAX to load content, or using a popup window with a separate player. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555250/how-to-keep-audio-playing-while-navigating-through-pages) is another SO post.

Comment: @area28 Thanks for your help.. I went through the link you mentioned but  could not found solution to my problem. I don't think I am looking for ajax/(history.pushState())  As I don't see any "#" in url of Gaana.com. on post back.

Comment: Checkout how Soundcloud does it. They have a fixed section at the bottom of the page playing music, and it looks like they reload the rest of the page.